# systemctl status shows inactive dead

Tags: linux, sh, systemd, systemctl

I am trying to write my own (simple) systemd service which does something simple.( Like writing numbers 1 to 10 to a file, using the shell script).
My service file looks like below.

```
[Unit]
Description=NandaGopal
Documentation=https://google.com
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=forking  
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/hello.sh &

[Install]
RequiredBy = multi-user.target
```

This is my shell script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source /etc/profile
a=0
while [ $a -lt 10 ]
do
   echo $a >> /var/log//t.txt
        a=`expr $a + 1`
done
```

For some reason, the service doesn't come up and systemctl is showing the below output.

```
root@TARGET:~ >systemctl status -l hello
* hello.service - NandaGopal
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/hello.service; disabled; vendor     preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
    Docs: https://google.com
```

Been trying to figure out what went wrong for the last 2 days.

Comment: Does the log file have anything in it? Are you sure you can write to that location?

Comment: did you make the script executable by `chmod +x myScript` ? Good luck.

Comment: @l0b0 Yes there is write access.

Comment: @shellter I guess the script had the write access.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

- You have set `Type=Forking`, but your service doesn't work. Try 
  `Type=oneshot`
- You have a "&" your `ExecStart` line, which is not necessary.
- The service is `disabled`, which means it was not `enabled` to start at boot. You should run `systemctl enable hello` to set it to start at boot.

You can check `man systemd.directives` to find an index of all the directives that you can use in your `unit` files.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. [:)] Type=oneshot and the systemctl enable did the trick. I was using a simulator environment and when I created the symbolic link for the service, it worked smoothly. :)

Comment: *"The service is disabled, which means it was not enabled to start at boot"* - That's not necessarily true. Systemd seems to sporadically lose configuration information, like setting a service or timer to enabled, so the timer or service starts when the machine starts. Also see [Systemd timer is lost after reboot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/512105/56041)

Comment: @PhilipRego You should create a new, complete question that states your complete problem. But use https://unix.stackexchange.com/ -- it's a better fit for `systemd` questions.

Answer (score 10):

Few points:

1. If you use `Type=forking`, it is recommended to specify PidFile.
2. In your case, `Type=simple`, and ExecStart without `&` will work.
3. use `systemctl start service-name` to start a service
4. Then use `systemctl status service-name` to check its status.
   status will be inactive/dead if service is not started.